# Installing with package-install-file

Tags: package, install

I am trying to install the [gauche-mode](https://github.com/leque/gauche-mode). Running the `M-x package-install-file` and giving the `/path/to/gacuhe-mode/` directory gives the Read error: is a directory, /path/to/gacuhe-mode/. How can i install it with this command otherwise? I am using emacs 24

Answer (score 2):

Installing a package from a directory (as opposed to a `.el` or `.tar` file) through `package-install-file` is only supported from Emacs 25.1; see [the NEWS entry](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.25#L519-L521).

You might be better off adding the directory to your `load-path` and requiring it:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/gauche-mode")
(require 'gauche-mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

a package that is not in elpa /melpa. can be installed manually.
You need to direct to the `.el` files rather than to the directory.
See [the following ergonomic-emacs post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_installing_packages.html).

- place the mode's folder in the `~/.emacs.d` path.
- `M-x load-file` then give the path : `~/PATH/TO/FILE/gauche-mode.el`
- follow the rest of the instruction for `paredit` and other functionalities in the readme on [gauch-github](https://github.com/leque/gauche-mode)